# How to center a spinner with autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am using this spinner in a project: https://github.com/misterwell/MMMaterialDesignSpinner

How would I add it to the center of the screen with autolayouts so that when the device rotates, it still stays in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add autolayout constraints programmatically. You can use 4 constraints - center x, center y, width and height:

```
[self.spinner setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSLayoutConstraint *centerXConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *centerYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:kSpinnerWidth];
NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.spinner attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:kSpinnerHeight];

[self.view addConstraints:@[ centerXConstraint, centerYConstraint, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]];
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, this works perfectly.  I had another question.  If I was adding a uiview overlay, I would need to pin it to the left, right, top & bottom superview.  How would that look programatically like the above?  I wouldn't need to add any height & width constraints because having the trailing/leading & top/ bottom constraints would auto expand it, no?

Comment: Yes, you don't need height and width constraints in this case. I answered in your posted question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboards you could add the Horizontal Centre in Container and Vertical Centre in Container. To do this, click on the view in interface builder and look at the bottom right of the IB screen. Click on the first of 4 buttons and check the appropriate boxes.

If you're using code you could write `spinner.center = self.view.center` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: The OP says he is using AutoLayout. When using AutoLayout, you must avoid modifying the frame directly, which is exactly what you are suggesting in code.

Comment: Sorry @EarlGrey, I just thought that my code was easier to get the results he wanted.